# How to add custom "typings" in typescript 2.0 / 3.0

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/) article typings system for typescript 2.0 has changed and so it is not clear how to attach custom typings now. Should I always create NPM package for that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean module augmentation (i.e extending modules)?

Comment: Just a simple thing, need to provide declarations for external JS code not covered with "@type" system (there is no way that I can publish those types through npm, the code and the interfaces are private)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can create local custom typings just for your project, where you can declare types for JS libraries. For that, you need to:

1. Create directory structure to keep your type declaration files so that your directory structure looks similar to this:

   ```
    .
    ├── custom_typings
    │   └── some-js-lib
    │       └── index.d.ts
    └── tsconfig.json
   ```
2. In the `index.d.ts` file, add a declaration for your JS library:

   ```
    declare module 'some-js-lib' {
      export function hello(world: string): void
    }
   ```
3. *(Optional: skip if you have TypeScript >= 4.x)* Add a reference to this type declaration in the `compilerOptions` section of your `tsconfig.json`:

   ```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./custom_typings"]
      },
      ...
    }
   ```
4. Use the declared module in your code:

   ```
    import { hello } from 'some-js-lib'

    hello('world!')
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure step 3 is necessary. It seems to work for me without it. Also it seems like that `index.d.ts` or `declarations.d.ts` can go anywhere in the project.

Comment: Yes, you can put your `declare module ...` into any `.d.ts` file.

Comment: Step 3 is necessary, but you only need to specify "typeRoots", not "types".  Also, you will wipe out the default path, so you should use "typeRoots": ["custom_typings", "node_modules/@types"]

Comment: @StevenSpungin, it seems that you don't need to specify `node_modules/@types` – at least not with TS 2.1.

Comment: Once you override typeRoots, it ignores node_modules/@types.  So "typeRoots": ["custom_typings"] disables the default behavior.  You need to add it back in.  This is clearly document in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: What is the difference above, if you want to use this custom typing in another project?

Comment: @StevenSpungin I've checked it with TypeScript 2.5.3 and you are correct – it is no longer needed to explicitly reference typed modules, and yes, you also now need to add `node_modules/@types` back. I've updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: What if you want your custom types to appear among declarations generated by tsc?

Comment: I have declared typings in same way but I am geeting error - Cannot find module 'testFunction'. while using import { hello } from "testFunction"; .
Is It require to register custom typings any where in angular ?

Comment: @doublejosh Did you found a solution?

Comment: @FernandoMontoya The solution I found is to specify ".ts" when I import my worker. I have no clue why ```import Worker from './worker.ts'```

Comment: Not sure about Angular, I just tried this in a blank project and it seems to be working, at least with default `tsconfig.json`. In fact, specifying `typeRoots` in step 3 doesn't seem to be necessary anymore 

Comment: Just tried the same and got it working without step 3 ("typeRoots").

Comment: @amethianil i have the same issue, have you managed to find a solution?