# How can I re-execute an external script in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have an external js file with a bunch of jQuery methods for the user interface. However, the Angular router is asynchronous, so user interface elements on other pages do not get properly rendered by the script, since they don't yet exist in the DOM.

Formerly, I was cherry picking some methods from the script and adding them to a method called `rerender`, but this is becoming cluttered.

My question was to see if there is a way to load and execute the entire script again inside of the `rerender` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import external scripts. Do it inside the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    System.import('script-loader!bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js').then(()=>{
      this.render(); // Do whatever, for demonstration I call a render() method
    })
}
```

Make sure in your `custom-typings` you have declared `System`:

```
declare let System: SystemJS;

interface SystemJS {
  import: (path?: string) => Promise<any>;
}

interface GlobalEnvironment {
  SystemJS: SystemJS;
  System: SystemJS;
}
```

**Option 2:**

Alternatively, you can put this into your module after the import statements:

```
require('bootstrap/js/tooltip.js'); // For example
```

Comment: I am using the Angular CLI, which does not use System to my knowledge, but I could be wrong. Can you verify this with Angular CLI?

Comment: It uses it. I have Angular-CLI too! :D

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. The import is executing, but the script is not working to my knowledge.

Comment: Check if your custom-typings has declared `System` like I posted in my updated answer. And check in console if the script is loading.

Comment: Perfect, it works. There was just a bug with a different page.

Comment: @wilsonhobbs Awsome! nice! I'm glad! :D

Comment: Can you add a link for noobies on how to add the system to the local-typings? Is it something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971984/how-to-add-custom-typings-in-typescript-2-0-3-0)? I need to create index.d.ts for my javascript file and the ts should contain what you posted in the answer? (sorry, completely newbie question here).

Comment: Agustin - yes, that is one right way to do it. another way you can also declare them in a file like declarations.d.ts in root, and include it with the "types" property in tsconfig. in general, the second is preferred if you have a small handful of files, but you'll want to do something like what you linked to if you have a lot of external js.