# TypeScript: override and fix typing definitions for packages

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, victory-charts

I'm using the [React victory](http://formidable.com/open-source/victory/) library for charts, and I'm using TypeScript. I have added the [@types/victory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/victory) package to my project, but unfortunately, it's missing a bunch of ***key*** definitions that I need. For some interfaces, it was missing a couple of properties, so (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971984/how-to-add-custom-typings-in-typescript-2-0)), I created a custom file to add those properties to the interfaces.

But, now I have a problem: the interface defined for events has a property named `eventHandlers` defined, but again it's missing an important definition, how it's defined:

```
export interface EventPropTypeInterface<TTarget, TEventKey> {
  /* other properties */,
  eventHandlers: {
    [key: string]:
      { (event: React.SyntheticEvent<any>): EventCallbackInterface<TTarget, TEventKey> } |
      { (event: React.SyntheticEvent<any>): EventCallbackInterface<TTarget, TEventKey>[] }
  }
```

But, the problem is that the function should allow accepting a second parameter, example (I'm not sure about the type of the second argument, so I have `any`):

```
{ (event: React.SyntheticEvent<any>, dataPoint: any): EventCallbackInterface<TTarget, TEventKey> }
```

So, I tried to include this property in my own definition:

```
declare module "victory" {
  export interface EventPropTypeInterface<TTarget, TEventKey> {
  eventHandlers: {
    [key: string]:
      { (event: React.SyntheticEvent<any>, dataPoint: any): EventCallbackInterface<TTarget, TEventKey> } |
      { (event: React.SyntheticEvent<any>, dataPoint: any): EventCallbackInterface<TTarget, TEventKey>[] }
  }
}
```

But now, TypeScript is complaining about the `index.d.ts` in the `@typings` directory, saying that `eventHandlers` must be of the type I have defined.

Is there a way to use the provided type definition file and somehow "augment" it with my own definition similar to what I did with other interfaces when just adding new properties?

Comment: I asked a similar question a few days ago, and gist of the answer was "properties in definition files can't be redefined": https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692419/1063392.  But I would be happy if this was incorrect!

Comment: Does it just *allow* another parameter instead of *require* one?  If so, maybe change it to optional, like `dataPoint?: any` instead of  `dataPoint: any`.

Comment: @jcalz I had the same idea, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can work. The problem is that the types were not defined with extensibility in mind.

Object literal types, such as `{x: string}` are great in many situations, but not for complex nested structures.

The reason is that these types, similar to type aliases, are *not* subject to the declaration merging needed to enable extensibility.

If the types of the possible values of the `eventHandlers` object were declared as an `interface` it could be extended with ease by simply adding additional overloads.

The following, self contained example shows how extensibility is quite easy when the types are refactored to use an `interface` declaration for the value type of `eventHandlers`:

```
declare module "victory" {
    interface EventHandler<TTarget, TEventKey> {
        (event: React.SyntheticEvent<any>): EventCallbackInterface<TTarget, TEventKey>
        (event: React.SyntheticEvent<any>): EventCallbackInterface<TTarget, TEventKey>[]
    }

    export interface EventPropTypeInterface<TTarget, TEventKey> {
        eventHandlers: {
            [key: string]: EventHandler<TTarget, TEventKey>

        }
    }
}
declare module "victory" {
    // this interface merges with the original, declaring additional overloads of the all signature
    interface EventHandler<TTarget, TEventKey> {
        // declare overloads
        (event: React.SyntheticEvent<any>, dataPoint: any): EventCallbackInterface<TTarget, TEventKey>
        (event: React.SyntheticEvent<any>, dataPoint: any): EventCallbackInterface<TTarget, TEventKey>[]
    }
}

type EventCallbackInterface<T, U> = {}
declare namespace React {
    export type SyntheticEvent<T> = {};
}
```

Test:

```
import victory = require("victory");

declare const handlerProps: victory.EventHandler<{}, {}>;

handlerProps({}, { x: 1, y: 2 }); // works fine
```

[Here is a link to it in action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20module%20%22victory%22%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20interface%20EventHandler%3CTTarget%2C%20TEventKey%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(event%3A%20React.SyntheticEvent%3Cany%3E)%3A%20EventCallbackInterface%3CTTarget%2C%20TEventKey%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(event%3A%20React.SyntheticEvent%3Cany%3E)%3A%20EventCallbackInterface%3CTTarget%2C%20TEventKey%3E%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20export%20interface%20EventPropTypeInterface%3CTTarget%2C%20TEventKey%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20eventHandlers%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20EventHandler%3CTTarget%2C%20TEventKey%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20module%20%22victory%22%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20interface%20EventHandler%3CTTarget%2C%20TEventKey%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(event%3A%20React.SyntheticEvent%3Cany%3E%2C%20dataPoint%3A%20any)%3A%20EventCallbackInterface%3CTTarget%2C%20TEventKey%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(event%3A%20React.SyntheticEvent%3Cany%3E%2C%20dataPoint%3A%20any)%3A%20EventCallbackInterface%3CTTarget%2C%20TEventKey%3E%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20EventCallbackInterface%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20namespace%20React%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20export%20type%20SyntheticEvent%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20module%20%22test%22%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20import%20victory%20%3D%20require(%22victory%22)%0D%0A%20%20const%20handlerProps%3A%20victory.EventHandler%3C%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20handlerProps(%7B%7D%2C%20%7B%20x%3A%201%2C%20y%3A%202%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D)

I strongly recommend that you submit a Pull Request to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped that modifies `npm:@types/victory` to use an `interface` in this manner to enable such extensibility.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Although I was hoping for a way to solve the issue, based on your explanation, it's not possible. One question: why did you declare `EventHandlerMap` in your code? I'm not sure I understand why it's there

Comment: @Farzad nice catch was an artifact from experimenting. Removed it

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Just one thing: can I use your code if at some point I get the time to submit a pull request?

Comment: You are of course most welcome to it. You may also link this answer in a PR if you find that helpful