# Export types from module

Tags: node.js, typescript, module

I'm writing code with ts for some time, but still I can't understand witch is the right way to export function and types from a module.

This is the context:

- Typescript 2.7, node 9.

  1. locale module A with exported function and types
  2. module B add module A as dependecy, and it uses functions and types exported from A

In my project, when I declare types, I prefer to use @types folder and d.ts files. For example:

```
declare type Message = {
   message: string
}
```

In this way it's unnecessary to import types explicitly when you use it.

But I can't undestand how can I export it.
The only way I can export types, is with interfaces.

```
export interface IMessage {
    message: string
}
```

But in this way I have to import then interface in ts file when I need it, and I would like to avoid this.

Can you help me to understand the right way?

Comment: Why do you need to export those types? You mean exporting them to be consumed by other projects? Because, as you said, by creating `d.ts` files, the types don't need to be imported

Comment: Yes, I would like to export types in order to be consumed by other projects.

Comment: One possibile solution:

index.d.ts:
    declare type MessageType = {
       message: string;
    }

index.ts:
export interface IMessageType extends MessageType {}

Answer (score 5):

If you need to export types to be used by other projects, change your `tsconfig.json` and add `declaration: true`. This will make the TypeScript compiler to emit declaration files for all your types.

Besides, you can export types from modules if you do

```
export type Action = () => void;
```

Then you can do

```
import { Action } from './module';
```

And it will work perfectly

Comment: I have that flag enabled, but it seems it doesn't work as expeted in typescript 2.8.1

Comment: this cannot be used with `"isolatedModules": true,` which it seems `create-react-app` requires...

Answer (score 1):

So i'm also new to typescript, but even though the first answer is correct, I'd like to build upon his answer,

1. Edit your `tsconfig.json` and add `declaration: true`
2. move all your types to a separate file and end the file with a `d.ts` extension e.g in the src folder, `/src/types/allTypes.d.ts`
3. now you can export your types

```
    export type projectsType = {id: string, clientId: string, name: string, description: string, status: string}
    export type clientsType = {id: string, email: string, name: string, phone: string}
    export type updateClientLastSeen= () => void;
```

4. Now you can import your types in any of your typescript files
   eg. in `src/graphql/sampleData.ts`, you do:

```
    import {clientsType, projectsType, updateClientLastSeen} from '../types/allTypes'
```

Comment: Do i have to explicitly import each type like above `import { a,b,c} from...` or is there a wildcard option to import every type from `'../types/allTypes'` like  `import { * } from...`

Comment: Still struggling on this topic 5 years later...I added the `declaration: true` option in tsconfig, but still can't figure out how to do a good configuration. I use to declare my custom types in the `@types` folder (in order to avoid to import types everywhere). well...the question is...how can I export the `@types` folder in order to make them visible outside the module? I also have arepo if you want to fork it and find a good solution: `https://github.com/wiulma/multi_module_sample`. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is impossible to do what you want "exactly". For example: typescript pack (from npm) uses the `interface String {..}` and then exports it. So, if you want to avoid interfaces i think is not possible, but you could add your custom typings file.

Here's an example: [How to add custom "typings" in typescript 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971984/how-to-add-custom-typings-in-typescript-2-0)