# Importing text asset into typescript with VS Code

Tags: typescript, import, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get typescript and VS Code to be okay with importing a text asset. I've got the compiler/bundler totally working, but typescript is acting weird about typing the import.

*src/index.ts*

```
import shaderSrc from './shader.glsl'
```

*src/index.d.ts*

```
declare module '*.glsl' {
  const value: string
  export default value
}
```

If I open only `src/index.ts` then I get this error on the `import` line.

```
Cannot find module './shader.glsl'.
```

However, the weird thing is that if I also open `src/index.d.ts` in a tab, the error vanishes and all types seem correct.

Do I need to do something special to get typescript to see `src/index.d.ts`?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971984/how-to-add-custom-typings-in-typescript-2-0-3-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your `src/index.d.ts` file to something else.  When `src/index.ts` exists, TypeScript normally ignores `src/index.d.ts` because it assumes that `src/index.d.ts` might be generated from `src/index.ts` and `src/index.ts` is more likely to be up to date.  Opening `src/index.d.ts` is probably temporarily forcing the TypeScript language service to load it.